# Create firestore index from firebase admin SDK with emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

The recommended way to create indexes for firestore is to use the query you're trying to do in your source code and then clicking on the generated link.

However, when using the emulator, and running the desired query, nothing happens. This is the query I am trying to do:

```js
await firestore.collectionGroup('collectionName').where('specificField', 'array-contains-any', ['']).get();
```

Since I'm using the emulator, it returns the correct response, but doesn't give me a link to create the actual index in firestore. Do I have to run the code on production in order to get that link?

If anyone also knows how this index should look like in the firestore.indexes.json file I would appreciate that too!

Comment: The error from emulator used to have the link as well. Can you try adding an exemption as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dacFq.png)? DO replace with the relevant field names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2027

tl;dr - as of Sept '22, the local emulator 'just works' and does not require (or warn/prompt for) composite indexes.

I cannot find any info on how to tease out the required indexes, so it appears devs using the emulator need to 'eyeball' the problem or otherwise somehow catch it themselves.

(Really sketchy aspect of Firestore emulator dev imo - yeesh.)

Comment: Oh ok, seems like it'll just pass. Thanks for letting me know. So that means we either have to run the query on prod or semi-guess the index. Tyty